# Unable to make Bootloader PC jump to application address 0x4000 in Program flash memory

Tags: bootloader, microchip, pic18

Can someone please help me.

I am using PIC18F26Q10 mcu
bootloader code starts from 0xF00 and application code starts from 0x4000
The below code is what I tried out but the switch doesn't seem to happen.
In debug I could observe the breakpoint hitting at 0x4000 but it dint work.
when I read the target hex using MPLAB IDE  all the code is in correct address location.

MPLAB IDE v5.45 and xc8 v2.45

where am I going wrong?

I have used the same code in PIC18F26K22 and PIC18F26K42 it works there

I am using :

```
`STKPTR = 0x00;
PCLATU = 0x00;
PCLATH = 0X41;
PCL = 00;`
```

I tried this as well:

`#define    RESET_ADDRESS_APPLICATION 0x004000UL STKPTR = 0x00; asm("GOTO " ___mkstr(RESET_ADDRESS_APPLICATION));`

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem. It looks like it doesn't like UL defined constant.

`#define RESET_ADDRESS_APPLICATION 0x4000`

...

`asm("GOTO " ___mkstr(RESET_ADDRESS_APPLICATION));`